# Coping a file content into a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have created a c++ application to read content of a file into an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("myfile.txt");
    int a[3];
    int counter = 0;
    char s[10];
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile.getline(s, 10,';');
        a[counter]=atoi(s);
        counter++;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++)
        cout << a[i]<<endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

and content if my file is:

```
15;25;50
```

and it's working fine

My question is :
If I change file to:

```
15;25;50

12;85;22
```

How can I read all of file into a 3*2 array?

Comment: Well , I couldn't find any way to do that :(

Comment: 1. Use `std::string`, not character arrays and `std::vector` instead of an array that overflows if you have more than three lines in the file. 2. Use `while (getline())`, not `while (!eof())`. 3. Use something like `stoi` instead of `atoi`, which has absolutely no way of telling if it was an error. 4. Prefer `std::whatever` to `using namespace std;`.

Comment: So, what do you THINK you need to do? How do you define a 3 x 2 matrix (two dimensional array)?

Comment: @Mats Petersson , I will define it using int b[3][2] , I know how to use arrays , Problem is I can't find any way to copt file content into them.

Comment: It follows the same way as you are doing currently. You will need one loop for each line...

Comment: I really don't know how to loop for each line ...

Comment: Get the whole line into your `s`, than do `strtok()` on your `s`, to split numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two delimiters, `;` and newline (`\n`), which complicates matters a bit. You can read a complete line and split this line afterwards. I would also suggest using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of plain arrays

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > a;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std:istringstream ss(line);
    std::string num;
    while (std::getline(ss, num, ';')) {
        int n = atoi(num);
        v.push_back(n);
    }

    a.push_back(v);
}
```

Using plain arrays is possible, too. You must then make sure, you don't overwrite the array, when you have more lines than the array permits.

If you have always three numbers in one row, you can also make use of this and split the first two numbers at `;` and the third one at `\n`

```
int a[2][3];
for (int row = 0; std::getline(myfile, s, ';'); ++row) {
    a[row][0] = atoi(s);
    std::getline(myfile, s, ';'));
    a[row][1] = atoi(s);
    std::getline(myfile, s));
    a[row][2] = atoi(s);
}
```

But this will fail of course, if you have more than three numbers in a row or, worse yet, have more than two rows.

Comment: You could use `stringstream` to convert from string to int instead of `atoi()`, as your code is strictly C++ apart from that.

Comment: or use stoi(), it takes a std::string as an arg.

Comment: @prajmus You're right, this or using `std::stoi` would be another improvement. On the other hand, if you have only numbers in your input, `atoi` isn't too bad.